# Adding a delay in FiddlerScript

Tags: fiddler

I would like to add a uniform delay to responses in all sessions that Fiddler intercepts. The use of `"response-trickle-delay"` is unacceptable, since that doesn't actually introduce a uniform delay, but rather delays each 1KB of transfer (which simulates low bandwidth, rather than high latency).

The only reference I could find was [here](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/emulating-slow-server-response-times-using-fiddler/), which used the following atrocity (DO NOT USE!):

```
static function wait(msecs) 
{ 
var start = new Date().getTime(); 
var cur = start; 
while(cur – start < msecs) 
{ 
cur = new Date().getTime(); 
} 
}
```

and `wait(5000);` is inserted into `OnBeforeResponse`.

As expected, it locked up my computer and started overheating my CPU and I had to quit Fiddler.

I'm looking for something:

- Less stupid, and
- As simple as possible.

It looks like FiddlerScript is written in JScript.NET, and from what I gather there is a `setTimeout()` function, but I'm having trouble calling it (and I don't know JavaScript or .NET at all). Here is my `OnBeforeResponse`:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
    if (m_Hide304s && oSession.responseCode == 304) {
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
    }
    setTimeout(function(){},1000);
}
```

It just gives a syntax error at the `setTimeout` line. Can `setTimeout()` be used from a FiddlerScript to introduce uniform delay?

Answer (score 10):

FiddlerScript uses JScript.NET, which can reference .NET assemblies, and `System.Threading` contains `Sleep`.

1. In Tools > Fiddler Options > Extensions, add the path to `System.Threading.dll`. On my machine, this was located at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`.
2. In FiddlerScript, add `import System.Threading;`.
3. You can now add lines like `Thread.Sleep(1000)`.

Comment: Step 1 is not required on latest version of Fiddler

Comment: Yes, just do step 2 and 3.